# Pull Request workflow validate code by pre-merging with Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

Lets assume i have the following build BFBuild. Now BFBuild can build multiple branches that can push packages into a nuget feed.

**BFBuild**

1. Develop - nuget feed with version number 1.1.$(buildid)
2. Hotfix - nuget feed with version number 2.1.$(buildid)
3. Production - nuget feed with version number 3.1.$(buildid)

When the **BFBuild** builds the **hotfix** branch build completion triggers kicks off other builds.

And all those builds will also push into their own nuget packages but with the same version in this case 2.1.$(buildid)

***Example***

```
- BFBuild
    - hotfix pushed to 2.1.$(buildid)
    Triggers
     - BFBuild 1
        - hotfix pushed to 2.1.$(buildid)
     - BFBuild 2
        - hotfix pushed to 2.1.$(buildid)
```

The code will always gets the latest packages.

The problem comes in when trying to validate code by pre-merging and building pull request changes.
The PR builds will increase the versions, so if dirty code gets pushed it potentially can break a lot of things.

How can I handle a situation like this?

Two Possible solutions i can think off is

1. Duplicate the builds and remove the task for pushing into the nuget feed. But this is a maintenance issue
2. Re-use the same build but add an custom conditional when to run a specific task. `and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))`
   So if a PR build triggers the build, push version 4.4.$(buildid) instead. The problem i see with this one is that after the PR build might trigger other builds and that those builds might push the wrong nuget version.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly and the answer was miss. I deleted it.

Comment: I am bit confused why are you triggering builds after the first one. Seems to me you are building same thing 3 times or it is different thing, but it is not clear to me. Is it just the case of hotfix, that needs to be applied to Develop and Production?

Comment: It was a difficult problem to explain...Yes i am triggering builds after the first build. So basically lets say "second build" and "third build" depends on "first build". So if there is a PR for "first build" then "second build" and "third build" also needs to run after "first build" was completed.

Comment: How "second build" and "third build" are dependent on the first one? If it is not PR, but merge it also needs to trigger those two builds?

Comment: Because "first build" pushed to a nuget feed, i need to make sure that "second build" and "third build" will also pass using those packages. So maybe depend is not the right word but i do need to kick the other builds off to make sure that they will pass before the code actually get pushed.

Comment: I see. Isn't an option to simply delete the package from the feed anytime "second build" and "third build" will fail? There is a nuget custom task, where you can specify delete argument. Task can be set to run only if previous task failed. May it help?

Comment: I can try doing that...but how would i know if its a PR build. Only "first build" will have a build reason of pullrequest. If first build triggers second and third build the build reason changes. So i dont know if second and third build got triggered by a pr build or just a manual build.

Comment: Just an idea. There are few predefined variables accessible during the build that might help. You may use for example `Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId = {Id of build that triggers other build}` under Control Options > Run This Task > Custom Condition to find if the build was triggered by other build. This value will be empty otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199053/discussion-between-r4nc1d-and-dropoutcoder).

Comment: How is your issue progressing?Is the idea of dropoutcoder useful?